# What's the difference between 調整する and 整える?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice

Both meanings are about adjust or fix, but I can't manage to understand why

> 温度を**調整した** ( right )
>   温度を**整えた** ( wrong )

If 整える usually means fix something to the right condition/state the second sentence should be ok as well.

Comment: What is the source of this usage prescription? Does it have a specific context? Or is it framed as a blanket injunction against 温度を整えた?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outdated answer:

整える is not used for 'to adjust'. My Japanese-English dictionary at hand lists 'fix' and 'prepare' for 整える. You don't say 'fix the temperature' in English, do you?

Answer (score 0):

整える does not mean to 'fix' something, but to prepare and make tidy. It can be used as 部屋を整える : clean up the room or 資料を整える : prepare and make the data in order.